# Есть ли слово "зачадённый" или "начадённый"?

Tags: словообразование

Задался таким вопросом. Можно ли от слова "чад", по аналогии со словом "дым", образовать слово "зачадённый" или "начадённый", так же, как от слова "дым" образовывают слово "задымлённый"? 
Лично я не вижу ни одной причины, почему бы не существовать такому слову. Однако ни один словарь его не содержит. Так грамотно ли употреблять такое слово? Если нет, то что этому препятствует? Ответьте, по возможности, конструктивно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос интересный. Понятно, что исходное слово - начадить, то есть напустить чаду. Тогда причастие должно бы образоваться при условии чередования д/ж - начажённый по типу "насадить - насаженный". Но действительно в словарях такого слова нет. Трудно представить, ЧТО обозначало бы это слово "начажённый" как страдательное причастие прошедшего времени. Что касается "зачаженный", то эта форма вполне возможна: зачаженная комната, то есть комната, в которой оказалось много чаду. Вот все, что я смог придумать. В источниках ничего не нашел.

Comment: Я предполагаю использование слова "начажённый" в приблизительно такой форме: "запах, словно начажённый". Т.е. зловоние, принесённое извне, при этом сравниваемое с запахом чада. Как вы полагаете, если я считаю такое слово стилистически оправданным, допустима ли подобная конструкция?

Comment: Ваши доводы вполне убедительны, а само слово "начажённый" соответствует правилам чередования звуков

Comment: Благодарю вас. Огромное спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Если ответ Вас устраивает, Вы можете его принять

Answer (score 2):

В качестве окказионализма (неологизм для конкретной обстановки) эти слова вполне возможны, но вне контекста вас могут не понять.

Словари фиксируют не все слова языка, а лишь много раз зафиксированные в различных текстах. Слова "по-случаю", вроде приведённых вами, возможны, но из-за их малой употребительности зачастую требуют дополнительной расшифровки.

Comment: Благодарю вас! Вы мне очень помогли! А какое из слов будет верным? С приставкой "за" или "на"? Вероятно "за", по аналогии с задымлённым, верно?
___
Хотя нет. Я сам понял. Можно и задымить помещение и надымить в нём. Оба варианта возможны. Спасибо.